# How to pass Object in asp.net webservice using iphone programming

Tags: iphone, asp.net, web-services

I am consuming asp.net webservices in my iphone application i am creating messages like

```
       -(NSString *)createChangePasswordMessage:(NSString *)oldPassword withNewPassword:(NSString *)newPassword withUserID:(int)integer{

 NSString *soapMessage=@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
"<soap:Body>\n"
"<UserID>%i</UserID>\n"
"<OldPassword>%@</OldPassword>\n"
"<NewPassword>%@</NewPassword>\n"


"</soap:Body>\n"

"</soap:Envelope>";

soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:soapMessage,integer,oldPassword,newPassword];


return soapMessage;

 }
```

But now I have to pass object in following webservice

```
   <xs:element name="UpdateSysUser">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>  
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="user" nillable="true" type="q9:SysUser"     xmlns:q9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyPass.DAL.DataCtx"/>  
   </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
```

So I don't have Idea how create message for this webservices I have created a class having following elements

```
       <xs:complexType name="SysUser">
       <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccStatus" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CityID" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CountryID" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Individuals" nillable="true"    type="tns:ArrayOfIndividual"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NickName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NickPrivacyID" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/> 
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserID" type="xs:long"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserTypeID" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
```

Please help how can I create message for above webservice so that i can pass SysUser Object from it .

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize you object to suit webservice request SOAP message , here SysUser.

```
// class definition of SysUser
[Serializable]
public class SysUser
{

    public string AccStatus;
// remining fields
}
```

Comment: its detailed [here](http://blog.exadel.com/working-with-ios-and-soap/) and [here](https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/blog/using-soap-web-services-on-the-iphone)